# Key value mapping in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two files.

1st file contains: (assume apple is key and fruit is value)

```
apple   fruit
banana  fruit
tomato  vegetable
mango   fruit
potato  vegetable
```

2nd file contains:

```
apple
banana
mango
potato
tomato
```

I need to loop through 2nd file and find matching value in file 1.
I need final output as: (fruit is key and apple,banana.... are values)

```
fruit    apple,banana,mango
vegetable    potato,tomato
```

Please suggest me the best and optimized way to do this in spark and scala.

Comment: why do you need 2nd file? result canbe derived frm 1st file alone....unless you want something like 'NA',chair

Comment: No. 2nd file is my input file. 1st file is the reference file from which I need to form the output.

Comment: what info are you getting rom 2nd file which is not there in 1st file?

Comment: 2nd file is my input. 1st file might or might not contain the strings which are in 2nd file and vice versa. My requirement is to get the output I mentioned above based on strings in 2nd file and taking 1st file as reference. Hope I'm clear

Comment: So, suppose your 2nd file does not have the string calle "apple". What would be output?

Comment: In that case, "apple" can be ignored.

Comment: How large is file2? (i.e. is it a short list or itself held in an rdd?)

Comment: file2 approx. contains 1000 strings (few strings repeat also). This is situation for now. In future the size might grow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-scratch").setMaster("local")
val sc= new SparkContext(conf)

val one = List(("apple","fruit"), ("banana","fruit"), ("tomato","vegetable"),
               ("mango", "fruit"), ("potato","vegetable"))
val oneRdd = sc.makeRDD(one, 1)

//maybe a Broadcast for this
val two = List("apple", "banana", "tomato", "mango", "potato")

val res = oneRdd.filter(two contains _._1).map(t=>(t._2,List(t._1))).reduceByKey{_++_}
```

EDIT: and a version that works entirely with RDDs so file1 and file2 can be arbitarily big (although if file2 is big, it probably contains duplicates, so you might want a `.distinct` every time in the `reduceByKey`)

```
val oneRdd = sc.makeRDD(one, 1)

val twoRdd = sc.makeRDD(two, 1).map(a=>(a, a)) // to make a PairRDD

val res = oneRdd.join(twoRdd).map{case(k,(v1,  v2))=>(v1, List(k))}.reduceByKey{_++_}
```

Output of either is the same:

```
(vegetable,List(potato, tomato))(fruit,List(banana, apple, mango))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val inputRDD1 = sc.textFile("file1.txt").map(r=> {
    val arr = r.split(" ")
    (arr(0), arr(1))
})

val inputRDD2 = sc.textFile("file2.txt")

val broadcastRDD = sc.broadcast(inputRDD1.collect.toList.toMap)

val interRDD = inputRDD2.map(r => (broadcastRDD.value.get(r), r))

val outputRDD = interRDD.groupByKey
```

Output

```
res16: Array[(String, Iterable[String])] = Array((fruit,CompactBuffer(apple, banana, mango)), (vegetable,CompactBuffer(potato, tomato)))
```

Comment: What if the 1st file doesn't contain any string from 2nd file and vice versa?

Comment: you will get None as key for those elements. 
outputRDD: Array[(Option[String], Iterable[String])] = Array((None,CompactBuffer(hello)), (Some(fruit),CompactBuffer(apple, banana, mango)), (Some(vegetable),CompactBuffer(potato, tomato)))

Comment: Or if you dont want to use option (you dont wanna waist resource on recoreds you wont be using) you can use flatMap instead of map.

Comment: Why do you read file1 into an rdd, only to run collect it immediately and turn it back into a normal (Scala) array, then list, then map? It;'s going to be the larger file so won't fit?

Comment: @Paul you are right, file1 should be read at driver from HDFS and should be broadcasted then. being lazy, I wanted to skip read from HDFS part.

Comment: I'm not sure. We don't know the sizes of the two files in the real use case. If they're large, they should be RDDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d=[('apple','fruit'),('banana','fruit'),('tomato','veg'),('mango','fruit'),(
'potato','veg')]
>>> r = sc.parallelize(d)
>>> r1=r.map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0])).groupByKey()
>>> for i in r1.collect():
...     print "%s  %s" %(i[0],list(i[1]))

veg  ['tomato', 'potato']
fruit  ['apple', 'banana', 'mango']
```

Comment: That just inverts the first file. You need also to restrict only to the content of the second file. A filter on r would do it :)